# Find unique tuples in a relation represented by a BDD

Tags: algorithm, binary-decision-diagram

Let's suppose I use a BDD to represent the set of tuples in a relation. For simplicity consider tuples with 0 or 1 values. For instance:
R = {<0,0,1>, <1,0,1>, <0,0,0>} represent a ternary relation in a BDD with three variables, say x, y and z (one for each tuple's element). What I want is to implement an operation that given a bdd like for R and a cube C returns the subset of R that contains unique tuples when the variables in C are abstracted.

For instance, if C contains the variable x (which represents the first element in each tuple) the result of the function must be {<0,0,0>}. Notice that when x is abstracted away tuples <0,0,1> and <1,0,1> become "the same".

Now suppose R = {<0,0,1>, <1,0,1>, <0,0,0>, <1,0,0>} and we want to abstract x again. In this case I would expect the constant false as result because there is no unique tuple in R after abstracting x.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done in three simple steps:

- Make two BDDs with restricted value of the variable you want to abstract:

  - R[x=0] = restrict R with x = 0
  - R[x=1] = restrict R with x = 1
- Apply *XOR* operation to this new BDDs

  - Q = R[x=0] xor R[x=1]
- Enumerate all models of Q

Applying this to your examples:

- R = {<0,0,1>, <1,0,1>, <0,0,0>} = (¬x ∧ ¬y ∧ z) ∨ (x ∧ ¬y ∧ z) ∨ (¬x ∧ ¬y ∧ ¬z)
- R[x=1] = {<0,1>} = (¬y ∧ z)
- R[x=0] = {<0,1>,<0,0>} = (¬y ∧ z) ∨ (¬y ∧ ¬z)
- Q = R[x=1] xor R[x=0] = (¬y ∧ ¬z)

Intuition here is that XOR will cancel entries that occur in both BDDs.
This is easily (but with exponential complexity) generalized to the case with several abstracted variables.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I would like to solve a more   general case. Instead of considering each element in the tuple as being either 1 or 0 I would like to generalize it to be any decimal number. for instance, the tuple <2,3> would be binary represented by the tuple <1,0,1,1> assuming the first two elements represent 2 and the last two represent 3. Consider that the relation contains the tuples: {<2,3>, <2,2>, <2,5>, <1,3>}. How could I compute the set {<1,3>} as the result of unique tuples in the relation above when considering the first component?

Comment: Done!. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375035/extended-find-of-unique-tuples-in-a-relation-represented-by-a-bdd) is the link.